# Create summary page of form inputs selected

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a 3 step form that uses jQuery to step through a customisation process. I have some checkboxes on steps 1 & 2 and want to create a summary page of those selected on step 3.

Once the user is happy with their selection I then want to email those selections to a specific address.

It uses jQuery so it's not a case of going to another page show/hide the correct steps.

**How can I show what has been selected on step 3? The emailing part isn't massively important yet but please bear in mind that it needs to be done.**

---

Here's the form:

```
<div class="entire_product">
    Content here.
    <a id="customise" class="configure-demo" style="margin-top:20px;" href="#">Configure new system &amp; get quote</a>
</div>

<div class="customise" style="display:none;">
    <form id="customisesystem" method="post" action="">
        <div id="first-step">
            <div class="steps">
                <p><b>Step 1 of 3</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="customise-area">
                <p>Options 1</p>

                <div id="customise-area">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hardware[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="second-step">
            <div class="steps">
                <p><b>Step 2 of 3</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="customise-area">
                <p>Options 2</p>

                <div id="customise-area">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hardware[]" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      

        <div id="third-step">
            <div class="steps">
                <p><b>Step 3 of 3</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

            <div id="customise-area">
                <p>Summary</p>

                <div id="customise-area">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery I'm using to initially show the form, then to step through it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var prevLink = '<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>';
var nextLink = '</a><a class="next" href="#">Next</a>';
var navHTML = '<div class="prev-next">' +
                         prevLink +
                         nextLink +
                      '</div>';
var prevLink = '<a class="back" href="#">Back</a>';
var nextLink = '</a><a class="next" href="#">Next</a>';
var navHTML = '<div class="prev-next">' +
                         prevLink +
                         nextLink +
                      '</div>';
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
            // init
            $('#customisesystem > div')
                .hide()
                .prepend(navHTML);
            $('#first-step .prev').remove();
            $('#last-step .next').remove();

            // show first step
            $('#first-step').show();

            $('a.next').click(function(){
                var whichStep = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');

                if( whichStep == 'first-step' )
                {
                    // validate first-step
                }
                else if( whichStep == 'second-step' )
                {
                    // validate second-step
                }
                else if( whichStep == 'last-step' )
                {
                    // validate last-step
                }

                $(this).parent().parent().hide().next().show();
            });

            $('a.back').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().hide().prev().show();
            });
        });


jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
$("#customise").click(function(){
    $(".entire_product").hide();
    $(".customise").show();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first problem is that you have multiple HTML elements with the same id. This is invalid markup. You cannot assign the same id to more than one element. The id attribute must be unique.

So, I will assume that you change it, and #third-step starts looking something like:

```
<div id="third-step">
    <div class="steps">
        <p><b>Step 3 of 3</b></p>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-buttons"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div id="customise-area-3">
        <p>Summary</p>

        <div id="customise-area-3-child">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So then you can use jQuery like:

```
//Retrieve the customization summary area:
var summary = $('#customise-area-3 p');

//Use jQuery to select all the checkboxes with the name hardware that are checked.
$('input[type=checkbox][name=hardware\[\]]:checked').each(function(k,v) {
    //Retrieve the value of the checkbox.
    var checkboxValue = v.val();

    //Add the checkbox value to the summary area:
    summary.innerHTML += checkboxValue + '<br />';
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yep sorry, that was a mistake when I was copying the code together for the question. They will be different. I'll give this a go in the morning. Just to clear up the questions - is that grabbing all the checked items in step 1 & step 2 (obviously a unique ID for step 2) then putting them in step 3 as checked items? Assuming then I can just submit the form as per normal?

Comment: It grabs all the checked items from 1 and 2, and appends their value to the paragraph element in step 3. Did you want to keep them as checkboxes in step 3?

Comment: I'm back and working on this now. I've just tried putting the jquery in and it's breaking the rest of my jquery. My question includes some jquery to show the Wordpress work arounds that are needed.